# C++ Code that outputs Numbers in Rows and Columns

Tags: c++, loops, rows

Beginner programmer. I have an assignment where I am to output numbers using loops. The input is the size of the output. The first assignment is to output the same #s vertically: For example. Input? 5. Output:

12345

12345

12345

12345

12345

My current code is incorrect but here is what I have:

```
int main(){
unsigned size;
cout <<"Size: ? ";
cin >>size;
cout <<"Numbers Vertically!" <<endl;
for ( unsigned r = 0; r < size; r++ ){
    for ( unsigned c = 0; c < size; c++)
            cout <<size;
    cout <<endl;
}
cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: so if your input is `5` you need to print `12345` 5 times? Based on what you said, on input `12345` you should print each digit on a separate line?

Comment: correct, vertically.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` for your main. Does your code even compile?

Comment: To get `12345` instead of `55555` (you don't say what you are getting now, but it's an educated guess) you may want to print `c+1`.

Comment: Forgot the }, made an edit, thanks. And yes my output has been 55555 as opposed to 12345. I will try c+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes.

First is to actually read in the input using `cin`.
Second is to print `c+1` in your inner loop instead of `size`.

Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    unsigned size;
    cout <<"Size: ? ";
    cin >> size;                             // Read input size
    cout <<"Numbers Vertically!" <<endl;
    for ( unsigned r = 0; r < size; r++ ) {
        for ( unsigned c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            cout << c+1;                     // Print c+1 instead of size
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
```

[**`Here is a running example`**](http://ideone.com/40271e)

Comment: Yes thank you both for this code. Can you explain why "c+1" just want to understand the concept of what's going on. Thanks

Comment: Because your inner loop variable `c` runs from 0 to size. If size=5, then your loop variable `c` will have values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 through loop iteration. However, you need 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. That is why you add 1 to `c`. Read this about loops http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html

Comment: aw gotcha, will do. Thanks again

Comment: Actually, since the *loop* value of `c` is not important (it would be if, for example, you used it as an index into an array), you could use `for (c=1; c<=5; c++)` and forget the `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a 'cin >> size;' instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned size = 10;
    unsigned n = size * size;
    unsigned i = 1;
    for (unsigned r = 0; r < n; r++ ){

        cout << i % (size + 1);
        if (i % (size + 1) == size) {
            cout <<endl;
            i = 1;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }

    }
    cout <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Cool share